# Support sw/hw h264 decoder in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc, h.264

I try to play h264 video via WebRTC in Chrome 55 for Andriod. According to this [site](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6417796455989248) sw decoder of h264 is available. But I don't see any information about h264 in SDP.

If to use Chrome Canary 57 for Android, h264 is playing. *#enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding* flag is 'by default'. But this flag is missing in stable version of Chrome.

It's possible to play h264 video in Chrome 55 for Android?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.264 works with WebRTC in Chrome on Android M57.